# How to create independent filter for each column with same condition in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have data in excel file for which filter has to be applied for each column independently but the filter condition is same. The reason for asking this is each column has that cell that meets the condition in a different row number.In table 1 I have 3 columns a,b and c. 
[image: table 1]

I want to filter each columns independently with value=20 so that the result looks like table below [image: table 2]

Comment: how about showing us some data?

Comment: @GowthamShiva Can you please answer for my updated question?

Comment: If its just 3 columns why cant you apply the filter manually?

Comment: @GowthamShiva This is just a sample data I have numerous columns in the real data file

Comment: Is it just 20 that you want to filter with all columns? If not how many values are there that you want to filter and where are they stored in the sheet

Comment: Actually I am storing the json key value pairs in each column, but the each payload does not have equal number of attributes and hence they appear at a different row level.

Comment: My question is, how any such values you want to filter? is it just 20? or you have more?

Comment: Let me put it this way, I want to know a way where I can apply filter to adjacent columns with the same filter condition(here in my case 20)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146678/discussion-between-gowtham-shiva-and-nagaraj-b).

Comment: How many filter conditions are there totally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this VBA code,

```
Sub matchvalues()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Sheets.Add.Name = "newSheet"
j = InputBox("Enter the value to filter")
Rows("1:1").Copy Sheets("newSheet").Cells(1, 1)
For i = 1 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If IsError(Application.Match(j, Columns(i), 0)) Then
        Sheets("newSheet").Cells(2, i) = ""
    Else
        Sheets("newSheet").Cells(2, i) = j
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This code will prompt the value that has to be filtered. Need to give that as input which will create a new sheet and output the values if present.

If you want to do this with just formulas, try the below. If the value that you are searching is in cell `E1`, enter the below formula in cell `G2` and drag across.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($E$1,A:A,0)),$E$1,"")
```

[image]

You can change the values in `E1` directly to see the updated result. Hope this helps.